# No Sound every second attempt in UWP and Media Player

Tags: uwp, media-player, wav

I have a very weird issue with UWP, MediaPlayer and Lumia 950.
It is supposed to play a short stop/success sound for my UWP attendance terminal. But every second attempt won't make any sound.

I have two questions: 
1. Is the MediaPlayer a good choice to play a stop or success short sound in UWP? Is there any better choice?

2. Is there any bug in my code?

   ```
   private void PlaySound(string uri) // function
   {
       var playbackList = new MediaPlaybackList();
       playbackList.AutoRepeatEnabled = false;

       var source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(uri));
       playbackList.Items.Add(new MediaPlaybackItem(source));

       MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
       mp.Source = playbackList;
       mp.Play();            
   }
   PlaySound("ms-appx:///Assets/Fail sound effect 3.wav"); //calling the function
   ```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just in case my new code may help some people.
I added some sleep time before play() and it works ok now.

```
    async private void PlaySound(string uri)
    {

        var playbackList = new MediaPlaybackList();
        playbackList.AutoRepeatEnabled = false;

        //var source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Reminder"));
        var source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(uri));
        playbackList.Items.Add(new MediaPlaybackItem(source));

        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();            
        mp.Volume = 1.0f;            
        mp.Source = playbackList;

        mp.Play();
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        //mp.Dispose();


    }
```